# Fourier Transform with Branch Cuts

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to compute the Inverse Fourier transform of the following function (it appears as a certain correlation function in a physical model I am interested it):

$$
\widetilde{f}(\omega) = \frac{2i}{\omega + \sqrt{\omega^2 - 1}}
$$

$$
f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} e^{-i \omega t}
\widetilde{f}(\omega) = \,?
$$

Can this be done explicitly? If yes, how does one do the integral and what is the answer?

If it cannot be done explicitly, then how can one derive the fact that $f(t)$ will behave as $e^{\pm i t} t^{-3/2}$ for large $t$?

This appears in Equation 11 of http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3657, "Matrix Models for Black Hole Thermalization" by Iizuka and Polchinski.

Comment: If symbolic math software and mathematical tables can't give you the answer, then we can't give it to you, either.

Comment: Why not? There are people who are really good at doing integrals. Plus, I am not just interested in the answer, I am also interested in knowing *how* to get the answer.

Comment: The people who are really good at doing integrals have found most of the ones that can be "done" in the 19th century, already. Did you try Mathematica?

Comment: I did try Mathematica in the form I wrote in the question, and it does not know the answer.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math problem?

Comment: Yes, it could also be in the Math forum. But it appears in a physics paper, see equation 11 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.3657.pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick sketch: first notice that the $1/(\omega+\sqrt{\omega^2-1})=\omega-\sqrt{\omega^2-1}$, which might be a little easier to manipulate. Now we compute it using contour integral. Close the contour from the upper half plane, but the contour has to come down and go around the branch cuts, chosen to be $\text{Re}\, \omega=\pm 1$, and you can easily convince yourself that the contribution from the big arc vanishes. Since there are no poles in the whole upper half plane, all we need to do is just to evaluate the contour integral along the branch cuts, which after a little manipulation becomes asymptotically $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-i(1+ix)t}\sim e^{-it} t^{-3/2}$ (this is for the $\text{Re}\,\omega=1$ branch cut).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to record a particularly pertinent comment by user CuriousOne that "answers" this question, and give some background to it:

> If symbolic math software and mathematical tables can't give you the answer, then we can't give it to you, either.

Indeed Mathematica in this case gives:

[image]

which, if you apply the asymptotic approximations for $J_1(t),\,Y_1(t)$ as $t\to\infty$, leads to the same asymptotic expressions as in [MengCheng's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/208371/26076).

Let's return to CuriousOne's comment:

> If symbolic math software and mathematical tables can't give you the answer, then we can't give it to you, either.

Why is this? Because just as [Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) tells us which algebraic equations have solutions in terms of radicals (e.g. the solution of a general quintic cannot be expressed as a finite sequence of linear and $n^{th}$ root operations for rational $n$), [Differential Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) can tell us which integrals can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Of course, you can *define* a new function in terms of the solution to certain differential equations or integrals, but differential Galois theory tells us when it can be expressed in terms of other, known functions. Analogously, the solution of the general quintic polynomial equation can be written in terms of the Jacobi elliptic functions.

Comment: Cool! I knew there were some theorems and I knew there was an algorithm, but I never looked at the details. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try Mathematica, but in the form I wrote in the question, and Mathematica does not know how to do it. MengCheng's answer is very useful as it tells me how to get the asymptotics analytically.